# How many dimensions are possible in C#?

Tags: c#, multidimensional-array

I would like to know how many dimensions are maximum possible in C#.

I know there's a limit, because it's not possible to create an array with 50 dimensions, because it throws a TypeUnloadException .

In Java the number is 256 as far as I know. I know that there's the 2GB limit, but it shouldn't be important here.

My questions are:

1. What's the limit (x86/x64 different?)?
2. Why does it exist?

   ```
   int[  , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , ,  , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , ,] fuuu = 
   new int[  1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,  1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,1];
    //throws a TypeUnloadException in VS2013
   ```

it doesn't work in VS2013

strangely this works [there](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/compile_csharp_online.php)

but not [there](https://dotnetfiddle.net/1OWi5Q)

Comment: 50 dimensions works with Mono's csharp interactive shell.

Comment: Is this purely hypothetical, or are you actually considering building a ludicrously large number of dimensions?

Comment: @JoeEnos: Well I remember a question on the IEEEXtreme three years ago where one had to implement a variable dimensional game and write a solver for that game.

Comment: Your example compiles in mono strangely enough.

Comment: In VS2013 it doesn't